# Best practice to live preview of CSS changes for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm familiar with the VM solutions to run Windows on Mac, but my question is if there is a software that allows me to style in live preview mode via VM for IE?

e.x. in CSSEdit on Mac you can see changes you make in the CSS file live in the browser. I would love to have this functionality for styling IE too.

**UPDATE:**
to make the question a little bit clearer:

I need a desktop/Mac OS application that allows CSS styling and (!) has a live preview functionality that works accross Windows VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Internet Explorer to play with, so I can't say for sure whether this technique will work, but you can make live in-page edits with Chromium, Opera and Firefox (on Ubuntu 10.10), with the following as an example:

```
<head>
    <style contentEditable> <!-- note the 'contentEditable' -->
        div {
        clear: both;
            width: 400px;
            background-color: #f90;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <p>This should start out orange. Ish. Please edit the above style to revise that, though.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

And with the CSS:

```
style {
    display: block; // <-- the important bit.
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6CKF/)

**Edited** to note that in Chromium, if not others, using a carriage-return in the in-page, editable, `style` block can cause problems.

**Edited** to add that while a carriage-return/newline using the <kbd>enter</kbd> button is problematic, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> works fine (in Chromium and Firefox at least, the others I've not tested).

Updated the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6CKF/1/) in response.

Comment: great trick, didn't know about that - will try it. But would love to have a software solution too, in case I don't have file access.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it *work* with Internet Explorer? (Seriously, I haven't got any IE to test it with...)

Comment: i was not sure if this might be helpful, but after playing around with it a few days now i love it - so accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be appreciated first.

i have a little trick to work with IE on your system. you need a FTP access and a domain to work using the trick.

> setup a account in Adobe browser lab to check how your website look [everywhere] and using firefile in firebug [who allow you to save file to server] you are able to change the css and you can save them on server. in another tab open adobe browser lab after a refresh you can watch the changes.
>
> their is some plugin in Firefox come for using IE in Firefox. you can use them to satisfy with the look in IE.

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#firefile.

Comment: guess the plugin you mean is IE Tab 2 : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36/ ?

Comment: ok, thx - it works, but ...

1. adobe labs is sooo slow
2. adobe works with screenshots - might be ok for static pages and an overall comparison, but doesn't make my life easier when styling js heavy applications

... in the end this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ezmilhouse i thing you need a Virtualbox or VMware then you can use Windows in mac OSX